# How to escape a % in magento translation

Tags: magento-1, localisation, inline-translations, magento1.9.3.1, js-translation

Inside Mage_Core.csv have the following line

> "Please input a valid CSS-length. For example 100px or 77pt or 20em or
>   .5ex or 50%."

The problem is, Magento expect this % to be a parameter, and gives me the error

> "vsprintf(): Too few arguments"

How can i ignore this '%' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a literal percent character, use `%%`

Reference: Magento uses vsprintf to format translations https://secure.php.net/vsprintf